# Cloudflare CNAME couldn't be verified with AWS Amazone

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudflare, aws-amplify, cname

I hosted an application on AWS Amplify, and I get a URL after deployment looks like this BRANCH.SOMESTRINGID.amplify.com. I want to change my URL to a subdomain of my domain (which is hosted by a third party, cloudflare). I have gone through the AWS Documentation and added a 'CNAME' record into my DNS but after 24 hours It shows that the 'CNAME' couldn't be verified.
can you suggest me a better way of implementing this
Steps I followed:

1. Add domain
2. Entered my domain (3rd party hosted)
3. Added a subdomain
4. Added a CNAME record in my DNS provider

PS: can you also suggest what AWS service should I use for Frontend application? (Currently I am using AWS Amplify, my Stack for Frontend is NextJS, Redux, Material-UI.)

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you still need the answer. I had the same problem just a while ago. Managed to work around it by switching the CNAME record from proxy to DNS only (by selecting the record to edit, and clicking on the orange cloud)